# Open Port for MySQL Amazon RDS with python or CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

I try to create a command line deployment for my war file to Elastic Beanstalk. It is working so far. But my last problem is to open the port 3306 for my RDS MySQL database, that my application can connect to it. My Deployment script can be found under : https://github.com/sven-hornberg-1314-fhb/Web106/blob/master/deploy.py

I'm using boto 2.23.0, Python 2.7.5+ , connRds (connection to RDS is working), dbeb is my database name.

First I created a EC2 Group first with my vpcid. and managed to open the 3306 Port for that group.

```
.create_security_group(name=group_name, description=descriptionval,vpc_id=vpcid)
```

Next I created a RDS Group over my RDS connection

```
connRds.create_dbsecurity_group(self.rdsSecurityGroup, 'rdsgroup')
```

My next step is to update the RDS group with the next lines of code. First I get the defined EC2 security group and try to perform the authorize method

```
    connRds = boto.rds.connect_to_region(self.region,
       aws_access_key_id=self.awsAccessKey, 
       aws_secret_access_key=self.awsSecretKey
    ) 

    instances = connRds.get_all_dbinstances('dbeb')
    db = instances[0]


    rdsgp = connRds.get_all_dbsecurity_groups()[1]
    myEC = connEc2.get_all_security_groups([self.ec2SecurityGroup])[0]

    rdsgp.authorize(ec2_group=sgEc2)
```

I get several errors, also with other code I post later, the first error message is:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-05-15/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
<Message>VPC DB Security Groups cannot be modified with this API version.  Please use  an API version between 2012-01-15 and 2012-10-31 to modify this group.</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>e48f8443-82bc-11e3-9861-6bf67b1543ed</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

My other try is to change the group on the db object:

```
instances = connRds.get_all_dbinstances('dbeb')
db = instances[0]
db.modify(security_groups=[sgEc2])
```

But results in an other error: **Cannot apply DB Security Group membership to DB Instance in VPC. Please use VPC Security Groups instead**.

But I thought I create a VPC Group by pass the vpc_id parameter ?
Do you have any hints or other ways to open the port over command line ?
(It must be over an API or CLI)

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress.html
AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress ? is there a equivalent method in boto ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Cannot apply DB Security Group membership to DB Instance in VPC.Please use VPC Security Groups instead**

Always remember a rule of thumb, ***when you have your stuff running inside a VPC, then ONLY the VPC security groups prevail.***

Other individual security groups e.g. RDS Security group, RedShift Security Groups...etc are valid only for stuff that is running in `EC2-Classic`, meaning, outside of VPC.

So, you are essentially trying to apply an EC2-Classic (in other words, RDS Security Group) to an RDS instance which is running inside a VPC. This is wrong and hence you are receiving aforementioned error.

Comment: My Ec2 Group seems to be a VPC Group, over the webinterface i can choose that group for my rds security group. :/ , I will try it in java, to check if its working

Thanks, but i think it is a bug, maybe it is the same as here https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/561 ? 
Even with the ID i get the error, data the api is outdated db = connRds.create_dbinstance(self.dbName,5,"db.t1.micro",self.dbUser,self.dbUserPassword, security_groups=[sgEc2.id]) 

then i get the error, that i have an outdated api call. i raised an issue in github. https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2010

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug, got it working with java 
https://gist.github.com/sven-hornberg-1314-fhb/8560467

maybe it is related to this bug : https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/561